# How to execute custom command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sh

I would like to build a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash          
/path/to/my/program/myProgram
MyCommand1    < — This is NOT a bash command
MyCommand2    < — Neither is it
```

Those are commands acceptable only by some sort of interactive session of my program. Any ideas how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo -e "MyCommand1\nMyCommand2"| /path/to/my/program/myProgram
```

or

```
/path/to/my/program/myProgram << EOF
MyCommand1
MyCommand2
EOF
```

When you want to have some delay in your input, try this:

```
(sleep 2; echo "MyCommand1"; sleep 1; echo "MyCommand2") | /path/to/my/program/myProgram
```